# Why is Package Manager Console giving me a message to Enable Package Restore Fix?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

When I go to Package Manager Console in VS2019 I see the following information

> ```
>  NuGet Enable Package Restore Fix
>  To fix package restore:
>  1. Please enable package restore in Visual Studio FIRST.
>  2. Run the command: Install-NuGetEnablePackageRestoreFix 
>  3. Restart Visual Studio.
>
>  This should fix that pesky broken build you are experiencing.
>
>  To uninstall: 
>  1. Run the command: Remove-NuGetEnablePackageRestoreFix
>  2. Uninstall-Package NuGetEnablePackageRestore
>  3. Restart Visual Studio.
> ```

Why is it telling me this?

I tried following the first set of instructions but the message remains.

Package Manager Restore is already enabled.

Comment: Hi Kirsten, any update for this issue? If you still encounter that message, try `cleaning the nuget cache`(Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Settings>Clear All NuGet Cache(s) after running the command `Uninstall-Package NuGetEnablePackageRestore` in Package Manager Console.

Comment: Thanks Lance, your answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it telling me this?

It's just a simple warning message coming from the old `NuGetEnablePackageRestore` package(Not from Package Manager Console component itself). Since you're now using VS2019, you don't need this package.

**Cause of the message:**

To restore packages easily in some old vs versions, there's one nuget package [NuGetEnablePackageRestore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGetEnablePackageRestore/)(last updated 7/9/2012) can work to help us restore packages on any given server.

This old nuget package contains `enablepackagerestore.psm1` and `init.ps1`. And here's the content of `init.ps1`:

[image]

So if someone consumes package `NuGetEnablePackageRestore` in current project or solution, the `init.ps1` will always execute and show that message as a reminder.

But for VS2015,VS2017.VS2019, VS contains the [package restore function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#enable-and-disable-package-restore-in-visual-studio) itself. So this package is not needed in VS2019, you can **feel free to uninstall that package** or j**ust ignore that** since it's just a reminder from that nuget package. (And this package is also not necessary in build server, `msbuild command=> msbuild ... /t:restore, dotnet restore ... and nuget restore ...` all contains the package restore function now)